# JSON Schema: required field

Tags: json, jsonschema

Im trying to use json-schema validation at some project, and want to ask about the "required" field.

In [current doc](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor61) there is a specifiaction:

> *The value of this keyword MUST be an array. This array MUST have at least one element. Elements of this array MUST be strings, and MUST be unique.*

But in another examples in the web, i can find something like:

```
"properties": {
    "foo": {
        "required": true
    }
}
```

What is a valid way to define required fields?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In version 3 of JSON Schema it was a boolean.
In the latest version, 4, it is now an array of strings.
The validator you are using may still be implementing the old specification.